# Simple way to serve files to multiple instances of client iOS app

Tags: ios, file-io, client-server

I suspect this is easy, but I'm not well-versed in server-side technologies so am looking for best-practices type info.

I have an iOS app that let's users choose fabrics to make a quilt. Each fabric is represented as an XML file with meta-data and an image of the fabric (the image is embedded in the XML as binary data). I want to put these XML files somewhere on the web and have the app check there for new files to download. So my requirements are simple: ability to filter files by date (i.e. get a list of files that have changed since the client last checked and the client can remember when that was), then download those files. Simplicity on the iOS/client-side API/SDK are is preferred.

Comment: Any web server will do: put a separate XML file, say, `index.xml`, with the name of the latest version of the file. Let the clients load that file, compare it to the latest version that they have, and load the newer file if it is available, or skip the load if they already have the latest file. The data files should be stored as static XML files as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. There will be 100s of these files, but your solution still holds - index.xml can hold times of all the files. However, once I reach 10K files (likely in the next year or so), that index could get to 1MB (each entry = date + path to file, and I may have subfolders so each entry could be 100 Bytes). So I was hoping for a way to just list files after a certain date.

Comment: Some things I thought of: Dropbox or similar, any servers which have file listing ability (not sure if any do), ftp if I can find a good iOS client.